# Incorrect set of vertices being used in XNA4 DrawUserIndexedPrimitives

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

**Background**: I'm writing a tile-based terrain renderer that uses GPU raycasting to render a heightfield. My graphics coding used to be C++/OpenGL, however I have decided to try C#/XNA4 (ie DirectX9) as bit of a learning experience.

**Problem**: Calls to DrawUserIndexedPrimitives appear to be using vertex arrays that were specified in previous calls.

**Details**:
The tile renderer works by rasterizing the back faces of the bounding box of the tile. The pixel shader performs the raycasting. The call to draw the box is this:

```
private void RenderTile(GraphicsDevice device)
{
    device.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives(
        PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 
        this.BoundingBoxVertex, 0, 8, 
        this.BoundingBoxIndex, 0, 12);
}
```

and to render the wireframe of the bounding box:

```
private void RenderBoundingBox(GraphicsDevice d)
{
    d.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives(
        PrimitiveType.LineList, 
        this.BoundingBoxRenderVertex, 0, 8, // vertex format is different here, 
                                            // but the positions are the same.
        this.BoundingBoxRenderIndex, 0, 12);
}
```

which produces this:
[image: screenshot of correct tile render]

If we use another tile by itself (the whole terrain is 2x2 tiles):

[image: screenshot of correct tile render]

However if we render both together, the bounding boxes are transposed:

[image: Two tiles - incorrect render]

I'm assuming I've made a basic mistake in the XNA code which has resulted in the tiles being rendered with the previous tile's vertices, but I can't find it.

The same set of data (a `float[]`) is used to create the heightmap texture and the bounding box, so it doesn't seem to be an error in the bounding box creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found the problem. I was setting effect parameters within a rendering pass (so yes, a basic mistake)

Original code:

```
    foreach (var pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
    {
        pass.Apply();
        effect.Parameters["HeightTex"].SetValue(this.HeightTex);
        effect.Parameters["Eye"].SetValue(eyePosTile);
        effect.Parameters["World"].SetValue(this.TileMatrix);
        effect.Parameters["View"].SetValue(viewMatrix);
        effect.Parameters["TexToView"].SetValue(texToViewMatrix);
        effect.Parameters["Projection"].SetValue(projectionMatrix);
        effect.Parameters["LightDir"].SetValue(lightDirection);
        this.RenderTile(device);
    }
```

Fixed:

```
    effect.Parameters["HeightTex"].SetValue(this.HeightTex);
    effect.Parameters["Eye"].SetValue(eyePosTile);
    effect.Parameters["World"].SetValue(this.TileMatrix);
    effect.Parameters["View"].SetValue(viewMatrix);
    effect.Parameters["TexToView"].SetValue(texToViewMatrix);
    effect.Parameters["Projection"].SetValue(projectionMatrix);
    effect.Parameters["LightDir"].SetValue(lightDirection);

    foreach (var pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
    {
        pass.Apply();
        this.RenderTile(device);
    }
```

[image]